# chartjs-node-canvas doughnut chart

Tags: angular, charts, chart.js

I'm using node-canvas module to export a doughnut chart.

This is my code:

```
const barChartOptions = {
responsive: true,
aspectRatio: 1,
cutoutPercentage: 75,
maintainAspectRatio: true,
legend: {
    position: 'bottom',
    labels: {
        boxWidth: 10,
        fontSize: 11,
        color: '#959ead'
    }
}
};
const barChartLabels = ['Vantaggi, Svantaggi'];
const barChartType = 'doughnut';

export const getBarConfiguration = (data: any[]) => ({
type: barChartType,
data: {
    labels: barChartLabels,
    datasets: [{
        data: [50, 20],
        backgroundColor: ['#69c499', '#fb5b5b']
}]
},
options: barChartOptions
});
```

This is what I get [chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jw02P.png)

As you can see in the legend I can see only one color but I'd like to see both (red and green as in the chart), moreover I'd like to show also tooltips.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is a minor typo in `barChartLabels` variable. It should be `['Vantaggi', 'Svantaggi']` instead of `['Vantaggi, Svantaggi']`. At the moment the array contains only one single string `'Vantaggi, Svantaggi'`.
2. To enable tooltips you could include `tooltips:{ enabled: true }` object to the options property.

Try the following

```js
const barChartOptions = {
  responsive: true,
  aspectRatio: 1,
  cutoutPercentage: 75,
  maintainAspectRatio: true,
  legend: {
    display: true,
    position: 'bottom',
    labels: {
      boxWidth: 10,
      fontSize: 13,
      color: '#959ead'
    }
  },
  tooltips:{           // <-- to enable tooltips
    enabled: true
  }
};
const barChartLabels = ['Vantaggi', 'Svantaggi'];  // <-- to fix labels in legend
const barChartType = 'doughnut';

this.chart = new Chart('canvas', {
  type: barChartType,
  data: {
    labels: barChartLabels,
    datasets: [
      { 
        data: [50, 20],
        backgroundColor: ['#69c499', '#fb5b5b'],
        fill: true
      },
    ]
  },
  options: barChartOptions
});
```

Working example: [**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/chartjs-doughnut-chart-5emo6v)